# recursive descent parsing and antlr

Tags: antlr

I run across several blogs, such as this one:http://mortoray.com/2012/07/20/why-i-dont-use-a-parser-generator/, somehow they use "recursive descent parsing" refers to handmade parser vs. parser generator like ANTLR.

To me "recursive descent parsing" and ANTLR are 2 different things, one is a general parsing theory while the other is an exact technology. But I am wondering why, it seems quite popular, people are mixing/comparing them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume it's just because handwritten parsers tend to be recursive descent because that form follows closely from the [E]BNF definition and is very easy to verify manually, and if necessary to debug. Conversely, tools like ANTLR, Bison and the rest don't generally produce recursive descent parsers.

So you're right in that the comparison is strictly an approach to parsing versus a tool for parser generation but somewhere along the way recursive descent and handwritten have become idiomatic synonyms.

Answer (score 4):

Recursive descent parsers are a specific subset of top-down parsers (LL).  Recursive descent parsers are what programmers typically build by hand because that is the natural expression when building things my hand. Tools can generate all sorts of funny machines. ANTLR's goal for the last 25 years has been to generate what programmers build by hand, which means that it generates recursive descent parsers. Necessarily the generated parsers are more complicated because they are not hand optimized by human.